# How to read value from custom HTML Table in Suitelet 2.0 in POST Method

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am Having a custom HTML Page in suitelet. I that HTML page i have a table with different tags. i need to read HTML table data and loop the table in suitelet 2.0 POST Method.

```
<table class="table" id="custpage_business_class_tb"> 
                  <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                      <th >Classification</th>
                      <th >Applicable</th>
                      <th >Certificate Number</th>
                      <th >Certifying Agency</th>
                      <th >Expiration Date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <#list ds.bussclasslist as busclass>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <select name="custpage_busclas_list" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">${busclass.values.name}</option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="custpage_busclas_applicable" class="d-block mx-auto mt-3"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="custpage_busclas_cert_num" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="custpage_busclas_cert_agency" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="custpage_busclas_cert_expdt" class="form-control"></td>
                      </tr>
                    </#list>                    
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

SuiteLet 2.0 post Method.

```
var lineCount = context.request.getLineCount({ group: 'custpage_business_class_tb' });
                log.debug('Total lines in Bank Details are:- ' + lineCount);
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far and what doesn't work?

Comment: @zelig63 i have a HTML page in that page i have some input fields and Table, i cannot get number of loop through the table in Suitelet 2.0 post Method.